# "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts" with C# MySQL connector

Tags: c#, mysql, database, mysql-connector

I am trying to connect to my MySQL database, which i can do over `localhost`. This works fine, and it connects successfully. However, when i try to connect using my Public IP, it doesn't log in. Being able to connect with my public IP is crucial.

So far i have:

- changed the `bind-address=127.0.0.1`  /  `bind-address=::1` to
  `bind-address=0.0.0.0`  /  `bind-address=::`
- Forwarded port 3306 on my router to the server
- rewrote the C# code
- tried from a different device (wouldn't even connect via LAN)
- checked Windows Firewall was allowing it through (Windows Firewall was off)
- restarted WAMP and Windows after each change

Everything is running on Windows 10 with WAMP hosting everything.

C# code:

```
private void Loginbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String username = user.Text;
        String password = pass.Text;

        String server = serverAddress.Text;
        int port = 3306;
        String database = "poppy";
        String connectionString = String.Format("server={0};port={1};user id={2}; password={3}; database={4}", server, port, username, password, database);
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            MessageBox.Show("successful connection");

            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + connectionString);
        }
    }
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: You are testing from a different network? - NAT often prevents access via the public IP from within the same network.

Comment: I just tried testing it off of a different laptop off of a different network, and the same issue popped up.

Comment: Never used the WAMP to install the MySql and such, but my advice is check if the port is the default one, if yes, Check the firewall it self. I have seen on some FW programs even if we add the port and such it will still block it, disable the FW just to test it

Comment: All forms of security on my computer and on my network are off. I no longer see any form of defense that could stop it.